# How to get the Row Number for a row after sorting using SQLite?

Tags: sqlite

My database table (Employee) consists of two columns (Name, Salary). I tried to sort the table based on Salary in descending order and get the corresponding row number based on Name. (To assign the rank based on highest Salary).

I tried this query

```
SELECT
    ROW_NUMBER () OVER ( 
    ORDER BY Salary 
   ) RowNum
FROM
    Employee
WHERE
    Name='Ram';
```

On my table, Ram gets the second highest salary. So I expect the output to be 2. But I got only errors. Please, someone help me with this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query returns only 1 row because of the condition:

```
WHERE Name='Ram'
```

So you will always get 1 as result.

Select the row number from the subquery with [`RANK()`](https://www.sqlite.org/windowfunctions.html) to handle ties for salaries and use `DESC` to sort descending the salaries:

```
SELECT t.RowNum FROM (
  SELECT Name, RANK() OVER (ORDER BY Salary DESC) RowNum
  FROM Employee
) t
WHERE t.Name='Ram';
```

Another simpler and maybe more efficient solution without window functions:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) + 1 RowNum
FROM Employee 
WHERE Salary > (SELECT Salary FROM Employee WHERE Name='Ram');
```